# Oracle left join behaving like inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have Two tables:

```
Dates:

  |ReportHeader|
  --------------
  |     2015-04|
  |     2015-05|
  |     2015-06|
Data:
  |ReportHeader|Customer|Sales|
  -----------------------------
  |     2015-04|    Plop|  684|
  |     2015-06|    Plop|  486|
```

I have my query:

```
select
    Dates.ReportHeader,
    Data.Customer,
    Data.Sales
from Dates
    left outer join data on Dates.ReportHeader = Data.ReportHeader
```

What I would expect back is:

```
  |ReportHeader|Customer|Sales|
  -----------------------------
  |     2015-04|    Plop|  684|
  |     2015-05|    null| null|
  |     2015-06|    Plop|  486|
```

The results that I am getting are:

```
  |ReportHeader|Customer|Sales|
  -----------------------------
  |     2015-04|    Plop|  684|
  |     2015-06|    Plop|  486|
```

Is there any reason to be found why this left join would behave like an inner join? 
Or do I just not understand how a left join is supposed to work.

The Oracle version i am using is:
*Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production*

Thanks in advance for any help extended

edit:
It seems i have over simplified the problem so i better put the whole query here:

```
WITH
    L0 AS (SELECT 1 C from dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 O from dual),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
    Nums AS (SELECT 0 N FROM dual union SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL from dual) ) N FROM L4),
    Dates as (
      select distinct
        to_char(to_date(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N))) , 'yyyy-MM') as ReportHeader,
        to_date(add_months(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N)),-1)+1) as FirstDayOfMonth,
        to_date(current_timestamp + (-1 * N))                               as ReportDate,
        to_date(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N)))                     as LastDayOfMonth
      from Nums
      where N <= 3 * 365
  ), Invoices AS (
    select
      TP.ID,
      TP.Name,
      h.FORMATTEDINVOICENUMBER,
      l.SCHEDULEID,
      to_date(h.INVOICEDUEDATE) as date_due,
      to_date(L.EFFECTIVEDATEFULLYPAID) as date_payed
    from  ODSTHIRDPARTY TP
      LEFT JOIN ODSINVOICELINE L on L.INVCUSID = TP.ID
      LEFT JOIN ODSINVOICEHEADER H  on h.ID = l.INVOICEHEADERID
    where TP.NAME not in ('<None>','<Unknown>')
), data as (
    select distinct
      Invoices.Name as Customer,
      Dates.ReportHeader,
      count(distinct Invoices.SCHEDULEID) over (partition by Dates.ReportHeader, Invoices.Name) as NumContracts,
      floor(avg(
        case
          when Invoices.date_due > Dates.LastDayOfMonth THEN 0
          when coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) < Dates.FirstDayOfMonth THEN 0
          when Invoices.date_payed < Invoices.date_due then Invoices.date_payed - Invoices.date_due
          else to_date(least(coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date), Dates.LastDayOfMonth )) - to_date(Invoices.date_due)
        end
      ) over (partition by Dates.ReportHeader, Invoices.Name))  past_due,
      Dates.FirstDayOfMonth as ReportStartDate,
      Dates.LastDayOfMonth  as ReportEndDate,
      coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) as calc_date
    from Dates
      left join Invoices on Dates.ReportDate between Invoices.date_due and coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date)
    where coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) >= Invoices.date_due
)
    select distinct
      Dates.ReportHeader,
      data.Customer,
      data.NumContracts,
      data.past_due
    from Dates
      left join data on data.ReportHeader = Dates.ReportHeader
 order by data.Customer,dates.ReportHeader
```

The troublesome part is the final query. **Select from dates left join on data**

For those interested, as @APC was saying in the comments. Create a testable use case. Doing that triggered me to rewrite the complete query that does work now. My initial premise was wrong and i took an initial approach that was wrong.

Revised query below:

```
WITH
    L0 AS (SELECT 1 C from dual UNION ALL SELECT 1 O from dual),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
    Nums AS (SELECT 0 N FROM dual union SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL from dual) ) N FROM L4),
    Dates as (
      select distinct
        to_char(to_date(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N))), 'yyyy-MM') as ReportHeader,
        to_date(add_months(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N)), -1) + 1) as FirstDayOfMonth,
        to_date(current_timestamp + (-1 * N))                               as ReportDate,
        to_date(last_day(current_timestamp + (-1 * N)))                     as LastDayOfMonth
      from Nums
      where N <= 2 * 365
  ), ThirdParties as (
    select distinct
      TP.ID,
      TP.Name,
      Dates.ReportHeader,
      Dates.FirstDayOfMonth,
      Dates.ReportDate,
      Dates.LastDayOfMonth
    from ODSTHIRDPARTY TP
    cross join Dates
    where TP.NAME not in ('<None>','<Unknown>')
  ), Invoices AS (
    select distinct
      TP.ID,
      TP.Name,
      TP.ReportHeader,
      TP.FirstDayOfMonth,
      OH.FORMATTEDINVOICENUMBER,
      TP.LastDayOfMonth,
      il.SCHEDULEID,
      to_date(il.invoiceReferenceDate)                          as date_due,
      to_date(iL.EFFECTIVEDATEFULLYPAID)                  as date_payed,
      case
        when il.id is null then 0
        else
          case
            when to_date(il.invoiceReferenceDate) <= to_date(coalesce(iL.EFFECTIVEDATEFULLYPAID,least(current_date,tp.LastDayOfMonth))) then
              to_date(coalesce(iL.EFFECTIVEDATEFULLYPAID,least(current_date,tp.LastDayOfMonth))) - to_date(il.invoiceReferenceDate)
            else 0
          end
      end as daysLate
    from  ThirdParties TP
      LEFT JOIN ODSINVOICELINE IL on IL.INVCUSID = TP.ID and TP.ReportDate
                            between il.invoiceReferenceDate and coalesce(il.EFFECTIVEDATEFULLYPAID, current_date)
      left join ODSINVOICEHEADER OH on IL.INVOICEHEADERID = OH.ID
), data as (
    select distinct
      Invoices.ReportHeader,
      Invoices.Name                                                                       as Customer,
      count(distinct Invoices.SCHEDULEID) over (partition by Invoices.ReportHeader, Invoices.Name) as NumContracts,
      floor(avg(
        case
          when Invoices.date_due > Invoices.LastDayOfMonth THEN 0
          when coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) < Invoices.FirstDayOfMonth THEN 0
          when Invoices.date_payed < Invoices.date_due then Invoices.date_payed - Invoices.date_due
          else to_date(least(coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date), Invoices.LastDayOfMonth )) - to_date(Invoices.date_due)
        end
      ) over (partition by Invoices.ReportHeader, Invoices.Name))  past_due,
      Invoices.FirstDayOfMonth                                                               as ReportStartDate,
      Invoices.LastDayOfMonth                                                                as ReportEndDate,
      coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date)                                         as calc_date
    from Invoices
                           -- and coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) >= Invoices.date_due
    order by Invoices.Name, Invoices.reportheader
), upvt as (
    select distinct
      row_number()
      over (
        partition by customer
        order by ReportHeader ) as ColNum,
      data.ReportHeader            ColName,
      data.Customer,
      data.NumContracts,
      data.past_due
    from data
), pvt as (
  select * from (
    select Customer, ColName, ColNum, NumContracts, past_due from upvt
  ) pivot (
    MAX(past_due) as DueDays, MAX(NumContracts) as Contracts, Max(ColName) as ColName
                for ColNum in ( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','10','11','12','13','14','15',
                                       '16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24')) pvt
)
select
  row_number() over (order by Customer) as No,
  pvt.*
from pvt;
```

Comment: Works for me http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cfb4eb038244b422fe56f396c70ab97c there must be something you are not telling us

Comment: Perhaps there's a WHERE clause in the query OP is running? (Does it have any conditions on Data table columns?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i am using cte to get the data needed. Only part of the data is in physical tables. Dates are generated from a tally cte. No where clause. Several cte in a row to get to this point. The final  query is much alike to this one though.

Comment: Well, you have simplified your example to a point where it's not showing your problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i added the complete query here. Hope it will make it clear what the problem is.

Comment: `where coalesce(Invoices.date_payed, current_date) >= Invoices.date_due` turns the outer join into an inner join. You need to move that into the join condition

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Changing the query and taking that where clause completely out of the query does not seem to make a significant difference though. The effect should have been negated because i rejoin the Dates cte in the last (finalizing) query.

Comment: @a_horse - but that only affects the result set of the `data` subquery. The OP needs to clarify which result set is the troublesome one.

Comment: @APC, The last resultset is the troublesome one. The one that feeds of the data subquery

Comment: Well the left join in the `data` cte isn't a left join, so it does not return what you expect, and if _that_ returns fewer rows, there is no way the left in the final query can "fix" that

Comment: I think you need to post a **reproducible test case** with table structures, sample data and expected output derived from that data. Because left outer joins work. If you're not getting the results you expect then there is something awry with your data or your understanding. Either way we cannot diagnose it without a solid test case.

Comment: @APC, you had the gist of it. I went back to the roots and started over rewriting the complete query from a different perspective. It does now exactly what i want. My starting premise/entity was wrong making it difficult to ever get out what was needed.

If you post a solution i will credit with marking it as the solution

Comment: Actually you did all the hard work. You can post a solution yourself. It is allowed, encouraged even ;-)

Comment: Alright, i'll do so. Just though that your remark triggered the action i needed and i appreciate the help that you and @a_horse_with_no_name have given me and want to recognize this.

Answer (score -2):

use below query

```
select
    Dates.ReportHeader,
    Data.Customer,
    Data.Sales
from 
    Dates, Data
where 
  Dates.ReportHeader = Data.ReportHeader(+)
```

Comment: I found that I add where condition at the left join query it self, then the result not showing.  if I use CTE WITH bracket over the left join quey, then add at the end of CTE: `select * from CTE where (my condition)`, then the data show, so the left join works good.